# Python Calculate Totals Until Current Row

Tags: python, data-science, data-processing

I have a football dataset with results of matches that looks like this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMhjt.png)

I need to calculate, how much goals, Home Team had in total, before match on the row, for [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWFWT.png):

If it is the first match this year or at all for the team, result in column will be 0. If same team, has second match, and in before games it scored 1, value in the column will be 1.

Find out that it is possible to do while itterating throw `pandas` DataFrame, using `.loc` funtion, where I am looking for same Home Team Name, and where date is lower, than the one, in my row. 
But it seems to take ages for 60K+ records. 
Any advice on how to do it faster? 
Thank you!

Here is example of code:

```
for index, rowin df.iterrows():

df.at[index, "Home Team Scores Totals"] = df.loc[(df["Home Team"] == row["Home Team]) & (df["Date"] < row["Date])]["Home Team Score"].sum()
```

Comment: Could you post the code that you are currently using?

Comment: for index, rowin df.iterrows():
df.at[index, "Home Team Scores Totals"] = df.loc[(df["Home Team"] == row["Home Team]) & (df["Date"] < row["Date])]["Home Team Score"].sum()